# When I ping from client (CentOS 6) to server (CentOS 7), it is giving error destination net unreachable

Tags: networking, centos, ping

I have two virtual machines on my laptop. One is CentOS 7 (server) and the other is CentOS 6 (client).

- When I ping from server to client, it is working.
- When I ping from client to server, it is giving error destination net unreachable.

Where is the problem?

> [image]

Comment: its working now.. thanx alot for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

### It might be the firewall.

On the server running CentOS 7, check the status of the firewall with:

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

If it is up and active, you should at least try to disable the firewall with the following command and test pings again:

```
systemctl stop firewall
```

If it works after disabling the firewall, then you need to adjust the server firewall to allow pings/traffic.